How do you make a module declaration for jlatexmath?
I have a hobby project in which I have a JavaFX app where I'm using the library jlatexmath to render math text with LaTeX into Image objects. For this app, I've also been using a module declaration to manage my project's modules. It looks like the following:
module project.main {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.swing;

    opens com.github.me.project;
    exports com.github.me.project;
}

Now, the problem happens when I try to incorporate jlatexmath into the module declaration with a line like requires jlatexmath. jlatexmath is the module that my IDE (IntelliJ) recognizes for the dependency implementation("org.scilab.forge:jlatexmath:1.0.7") (Gradle Kotlin). Trying to import anything from jlatexmath results in my IDE prompting me to add that requires jlatexmath line (for obvious reasons). Doing so, however, just results in errors at the compile stage telling me that the module is not found, anyway, even though my IDE's autofill recognizes that the module exists when I add it to module-info. I've changed the dependency and the requires statement in module-info to include the prefix org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath, separately and together, but that does not fix the problem.
The really confusing part for me is that I know the IDE isn't being wonky, since my dependencies are correct. I know that, because if I just remove my module-info.java file entirely, the app works with jlatexmath like it's supposed to.
I could continue developing this app without a module-info.java file, but it's my understanding as someone that's not in the computer science or software engineering industries that doing so is not a best practice if someone wants to come along and run this app on their machine instead of mine. How should I go about this problem?

I found jlatexmath on Maven central (since I never heard of it before reading your question) and the JAR file is compiled with Java 8 which means it is non-modular. I did a quick search but I couldn't find how to include a non-modular JAR into a modular Java application.

If you switch to Maven, instead of Gradle, Maven will put everything on the module path.  This allows you to require jlatexmath as an automatic module, by placing requires jlatexmath; in your module-info and adding jlatexmath as a maven dependency, then resyncing your maven project with your IDE.  By depending on an automatic module, you lose some of the benefits of modularization (such as the ability to to just jlink) - there is no easy way around that.

Compiler Error
You're using Gradle as your build tool. When building Java Platform Module System (JPMS) modules Gradle will only put dependencies on the module-path under certain conditions. From the documentation of The Java Library Plugin:

To tell the Java compiler that a Jar is a module, as opposed to a traditional Java library, Gradle needs to place it on the so called module path. It is an alternative to the classpath, which is the traditional way to tell the compiler about compiled dependencies. Gradle will automatically put a Jar of your dependencies on the module path, instead of the classpath, if these three things are true:

java.modularity.inferModulePath is not turned off

We are actually building a module (as opposed to a traditional library) which we expressed by adding the module-info.java file. (Another option is to add the Automatic-Module-Name Jar manifest attribute as described further down.)

The Jar our module depends on is itself a module, which Gradles [sic] decides based on the presence of a module-info.class — the compiled version of the module descriptor — in the Jar. (Or, alternatively, the presence of an Automatic-Module-Name attribute the Jar manifest)



The last point is important in this case. Also, note the documentation of The Application Plugin references the above documentation.
From looking at org.scilab.forge:jlatexmath on Maven Central it appears the latest version, which is version 1.0.7 and the version you are using, was released in 2018. If you download the JAR from Maven Central and look at its contents, you'll see it has no module-info descriptor and its manifest does not have an Automatic-Module-Name attribute. And the GitHub repository shows the last commit to master was about 3 years ago (2021). There was an issue to modularize the library, but apparently no progress was made and the person who opened the issue closed it by saying they forked the repository.
In short, it looks like jlatexmath is no longer actively developed and no progress was made towards modularizing the library before development stopped. And since the library does not have a module-info descriptor nor an Automatic-Module-Name attribute, Gradle does not place it on the module-path. Thus, the module is not found when compiling your module.
Clearly IntelliJ does not follow the same rules when determining if a module is present.

Possible Solutions
There are a few things you might try to solve this problem.

Use Maven instead of Gradle. From a comment by @jewelsea:

If you switch to Maven, instead of Gradle, Maven will put everything on the module path. This allows you to require jlatexmath as an automatic module, by placing requires jlatexmath; in your module-info and adding jlatexmath as a maven dependency, then resyncing your maven project with your IDE.


Try to inject a module-info descriptor or Automatic-Module-Name attribute into the jlatexmath library. I believe there are Gradle plugins that attempt this, but I don't know how well they work. I personally would not try this approach unless truly necessary.

Fork the jlatexmath repository and modularize the library yourself or find an existing fork. Then use the artifact built from the fork as a dependency instead of the original.

See if a plugin like https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin solves the problem.

Make your code non-modular by removing your module-info.java file.


The easiest solution is probably number 5: Make your code non-modular. As noted in the same comment by @jewelsea, you lose some benefits of modules once you depend on an automatic module. The primary benefit you lose is the ability to include your module in a runtime image built by jlink, because that tool cannot work with automatic modules. However, you can still deploy a non-modular JavaFX application relatively simply:

You can use jpackage to create a self-contained application. This tool is capable of packaging non-modular applications. Plus, you can configure it to put the JavaFX modules in the runtime image (created implicitly or explicitly by jlink) so that they're loaded as named modules, while your code and other dependencies are put on the class-path.
Note the jpackage tool does not support cross-platform compilation (e.g., you cannot create a Linux package on Windows nor vice versa).

Currently, as of JavaFX 23, you can still deploy JavaFX applications as a so-called "fat" executable JAR file. But be warned this will result in a technically unsupported configuration (and a warning will be emitted). JavaFX only supports being loaded from the module-path into named modules.
Note there is currently no standard way to have multiple modules in a single JAR file and launching JARs with the -jar option puts everything on the class-path. If you create a fat executable JAR file, any and all modules you included in the JAR will be lost/ignored at run-time. So, if this is your deployment strategy, then it doesn't make much sense to modularize your code in the first place.

Another option is to require your end users have a JRE that includes JavaFX installed on their system. Or otherwise have JavaFX "installed" in some way. This is likely not a viable option unless you control the end users' computers, or unless your end users are more likely to be technically proficient.



Thank you for the extremely thorough and very informative explanation.
